# Not able to login to my indeed account using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

On line:

```
Set ieElement = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("sg-btn sg-btn-primary btn-signin")
```

`ieElement.Click` of the below code throws an error called "Object does not support this property or method".

```
Sub login()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim uid As String
    Dim pwd As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ieElement As Object

    Set sh = Sheets("Indeed Resume Download")
    Set rng = sh.Range("A2")

    On Error Resume Next
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

    uid = rng.Value
    pwd = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Dim j As Long

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer 'Initialize internet object
    objIE.Navigate "https://secure.indeed.com/account/loginservice=my&hl=en_IN&co=IN&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indeed.co.in%2F"
    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.Document.all.signin_email.Value = UserID    
    objIE.Document.all.signin_password.Value = Password

    Set ieElement = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("sg-btn sg-btn-primary btn-signin")
    ieElement.Click

    For j = 2 To sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp).Row

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    With objIE
    .Navigate sh.Range("CA" & j).Value

    Do While .Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Do While .Busy: Loop
    Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
    Do While .Busy: Loop

    End With

    Do While objIE.Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Next j

    Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You define `uid` and `pwd` but then when you are using them, you are calling them `UserID` and `Password` - is that intentional or a bug?

Comment: Jean, This is intentional to hide credentials. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `getElementsByClassName`, you have to determine which class name you are wanting, as there can be many. If your class name is unique (which in this case it appears it could be), you can simply add a (0) to the end. If you want to search through all the class names you could use a `For Each...Next` statement.

Notice the different between these:
`getElementByID()` and `getElementsByClassName()`? Elements is plural when used with ClassName, so you need to designate which element of that class you want.

Try replacing your line with this:

```
Set ieElement = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("sg-btn sg-btn-primary btn-signin")(0)
```

The method you are currently using would work along these lines:

```
Dim ieElements, ieElemBtn, ieElement
Set ieElements = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("sg-btn sg-btn-primary btn-signin")
For Each ieElement in ieElements
    If ieElement ..... Then 
        Set ieElemBtn = ieElement
        Exit For
    End If
Next ieElement 
ieElemBtn.Click
```